# not able to send email but able to recieve it in SES

Tags: sendmail, amazon-ses

I have set my mx record value to  **10 inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com** for email recieving feature.
Now I am only able to recieve the message but not able to send it.
Is there any possible way to do both in the MX record values.
Because I need sending and recieving the mails.

I tried clubbing the values in mx records like below.

```
1 aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com. 
10 inbound-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
15 q2g53xh2gmgoo2olmsg4hnez5m6yaubufldbr2wpxbazavpctn7q.mx-verification.google.com.
5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

But its not working.
Any solutions??